# Using native looking macOS menu buttons in Qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt

Is there a possibility to use menu buttons in qt that look like the ones used in many macOS applications such as e.g. safari, pages, ...?

I mean those small looking buttons in the menu bar with white background.
Currently I'm using qt 4.8 but could switch to 5.x if this would help.

Comment: Wouldn't it look weird to have macOS style buttons on a Windows/Linux machine? :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 - Native Win32 controls look really dated. But it's really a design decision (i.e. developer preference).

Comment: @selbie "Native" Win32 controls look appropriately to a given version of Windows. E.g. on Windows 10 they'll look modern, while on Windows XP they'll look retro.